# Binomial distribution question, find the possible values of $n$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, binomial-distribution

The random variable $X$ has probability distribution $Bi(n, p)$

Given that: $Pr(X=1)$ = $(1-p)^{n-2}$, p < 1.

Find the possible values of $n$ and the value(s) of $p$ in terms of $n$.

What I have done so far:

Using the rule for binomial probability:

$\to$$Pr(X = 1)$ = $n\choose{1}$ $p^1 (1-p)^{n-1}$

$\to$$np(1-p)^{n-1} = (1-p)^{n-2}$

$\to$$(1-p)^{n-1}(np-(1-p)^{-1})=0$

$\to$$np-(\frac{1}{1-p}) =0$

$\to$$-np +np^2+1=0$

I need help after this step. Thanks a lot! :))

Comment: Have you tried isolating $n$?  Observe that $np^2 - np + 1 = 0$ is a quadratic equation in $p$.

Comment: Solve $np(1-p)^{n-1}=(1-p)^{n-2}$ into $n=\ldots$, the right side is a function of $p$, where $p\in[0,1]$. Calculate minimum and maximum of this function with variables in $[0,1]$. You should be able to find both $n$ and $p$ from that.

Comment: More precisely: Minimum and maximum of that function gives you a range for $n$. After that, you just have to solve the quadratic equation $np(1-p)-1=0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, user408858 Good point!, I tried solving using the quadratic formula but just end up getting $n>0$, which is not correct.

$p = \frac{n+\sqrt{n^2-4n}}{2n}$

$p = \frac{n-\sqrt{n^2-4n}}{2n}$

This gives me: $n>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve for $n$: Isolate $n$, factor, then divide.
\begin{align*}
np^2 - np + 1 & = 0\\
np^2 - np & = -1\\
n(p^2 - p) & = -1
\end{align*}
If $p = 0$, the equation is always false.  If $0 < p < 1$, $p^2 < p$, so $p^2 - p \neq 0$.  Therefore, we can divide by $p^2 - p$ which yields
$$n = -\frac{1}{p^2 - p} = \frac{1}{p - p^2} = \frac{1}{p(1 - p)}$$
with the restriction that $n$ is a positive integer.

To solve for $p$:  Apply the Quadratic Formula to the quadratic in $p$.
$$p = \frac{n \pm \sqrt{n^2 - 4n}}{2n}$$
Since $p$ is a real number, we require that $n^2 - 4n \geq 0$.  Since $n^2 - 4n = n(n - 4)$, $n^2 - 4n \geq 0$ if $n \geq 4$ or $n \leq 0$.  Since $n$ is a nonnegative integer, $n \geq 4$ or $n = 0$.  If $n = 0$, $p$ is undefined.  Thus, $n \geq 4$.

You should verify that
$$0 < \frac{n \pm \sqrt{n^2 - 4n}}{2n} < 1$$
whenever $n \geq 4$.

The restriction that $n$ is an integer satisfying $n \geq 4$ must also apply to the equation
$$n = \frac{1}{p(1 - p)}$$

**Note:**  After the step
$$np(1 - p)^{n - 1} = (1 - p)^{n - 2}$$
you could have proceeded as follows:
\begin{align*}
np(1 - p)^{n - 1} - (1 - p)^{n - 2} & = 0\\
(1 - p)^{n - 2}[np(1 - p) - 1] & = 0\\
(1 - p)^{n - 2}[np - np^2 - 1] & = 0
\end{align*}
Since $p < 1$, $1 - p > 0$.  Thus, we can divide by $(1 - p)^{n - 2}$ to obtain $np - np^2 - 1 = 0$ or, equivalently, $np^2 - np + 1 = 0$ without introducing negative exponents or fractions.

Comment: I have a question, why did you only take the discriminant to be $> 0$ and not the entire fraction?

Comment: In order to obtain a real value, we require that the discriminant be nonnegative.

Comment: @Taussig Thanks!